# creating an object with has_many association results in NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

Controllers

```
class ExperiencesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @resume = Resume.find(params[:resume])
    @experience = @resume.build_experience(params[:experience])
  end
end

class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @resume = Resume.new(params[:resume])
    @resume.build_webconnection
    @resume.build_experience   # <<<<<<<<< Error occurs here

    if @resume.save
      #UserMailer.created_resume_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to @resume
    else
      @title = "Create a new resume"
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Models

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resume
end

class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one   :webconnection
  has_many  :experiences
end
```

Error Message when I try to create a Resume (which also creates an Experience associated with Resume)

```
NoMethodError in ResumesController#create
undefined method `build_experience' for #<Resume:0xbb428a4>
```

I feel like I have everything pretty much in place, but missing an 's' or something somewhere. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would normally use `build_experience` when using a `has_one` or a `belongs_to` association. It's working for `webconnection` because it is a `has_one` association.

There's a difference with `has_many` associations though: you must call the `build` method on the association, like this: `resume.experiences.build`. This indicates

Because this is a `has_many` association and not a `has_one` or a `belongs_to`, you should be using `resume.experiences.build`.

Answer (score 1):

Henceforth if you got such error, there is simplest way to check methods like this-
e.g. @resume.methods you will get list of methods.